How to Include a Shell Command in npm Scripts Entry?
There is a shell command that is used to copy all HTML files from one directory to another while preserving the directory structure:
find ./src -name '*.html' -exec sh -c 'mkdir -p "./dist/$(dirname "{}")" && cp "{}" "./dist/{}"' \;

The goal is to include this command in the npm scripts entry in package.json. However, it's unclear how to properly escape the command to make it work. Here's what has been tried:
"scripts": {
  "copy-html": "find ./src -name '*.html' -exec sh -c 'mkdir -p \"./dist/$(dirname \"{}\")\" && cp \"{}\" \"./dist/{}\"' \\;"
}

When running npm run copy-html, the following error occurs:
find: missing argument to `-exec'

What is the correct way to include this command in the npm scripts entry and resolve this error?
Note:

Currently, user is using git bash to run this.
User already gets around this by creating a separate bash file and calling that from npm script.
User wants to find a solution to properly escape because this command is just an example and there are numerous other commands user would like to escape/use without having to create bash files for each command.


What about putting the find command into a file scripts/copy-html.sh, and then in your scripts section just reference ./scripts/copy-html.sh? That removes the escaping problem and means you get proper linting/formatting/etc when editing your shell script.

I can't reproduce the problem. Using this package.json, which I believe has the identical entry for copy-html, running npm run copy-html successfully executes the find command and copies html files from src into dist.
